# Python json log creation and processing

Tags: python, json, logging

Using python logging, I create a log file in json format. Each line is a valid json and the whole log is just many lines of json. It is basically logging dta from some sensors. My code also controls some settings of those sensors.
I create loggers as per example below:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger

formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(message)s')

log = logging.getLogger('MSG')
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
              filename='C:\\TEMP\\LOG\\test.log', maxBytes=2097152, backupCount=5)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(fh)

res = logging.getLogger('RES')
res.setLevel(logging.INFO)
res.addHandler(fh)

stg = logging.getLogger('SET')
stg.setLevel(logging.INFO)
stg.addHandler(fh)
```

The log file created by my code and the above loggers looks more or less like this:

```
{"asctime": "2016-05-13 11:25:32,154", "name": "SET", "message": "", "VAR": "Vdd", "VAL": "1"}
{"asctime": "2016-05-13 11:25:32,155", "name": "MSG", "message": "writting new setting successful"}
{"asctime": "2016-05-13 11:25:32,155", "name": "RES", "message": "", "VAR": "TEMP", "VAL": "23"}
{"asctime": "2016-05-13 11:25:32,157", "name": "RES", "message": "", "VAR": "LUX", "VAL": "150"}
{"asctime": "2016-05-13 11:25:32,159", "name": "SET", "message": "", "VAR": "Vdd", "VAL": "2"}
{"asctime": "2016-05-13 11:25:32,164", "name": "MSG", "message": "writting new setting successful"}
{"asctime": "2016-05-13 11:25:32,166", "name": "RES", "message": "", "VAR": "TEMP", "VAL": "25"}
{"asctime": "2016-05-13 11:25:32,171", "name": "RES", "message": "", "VAR": "LUX", "VAL": "170", "extra": "OV detected"}
{"asctime": "2016-05-13 11:25:32,177", "name": "SET", "message": "", "VAR": "Vdd", "VAL": "3"}
{"asctime": "2016-05-13 11:25:32,178", "name": "MSG", "message": "writting new setting successful"}
{"asctime": "2016-05-13 11:25:32,178", "name": "RES", "message": "", "VAR": "TEMP", "VAL": "28"}
{"asctime": "2016-05-13 11:25:32,178", "name": "RES", "message": "", "VAR": "LUX", "VAL": "190"}
```

Now my first question. Can I be sure that the lines in the log file will be written in the same order they are executed in Python code? (this was not always true when I was simple doing "print" to the console). If not how to ensure that? I  was trying to scan the continuity of timestamps, but I noticed that even upto four lines can have the same timestamp.

As you can see I am setting one parameter logger('SET') Vdd = 1 .. 3 and reading a series of measurement results logger('RES') Temp,Lux. So my second question, what is the best way to parse this log file if I want to create a csv file or just create a stacked plot (Temp, Lux) vs Vdd ? (Note that there can be a variable number of keywards in each log line, there can be oder log messages so the log lines have to be filtered and the log file can be large)
I would want the procedure to be as generic and flexible as possible, as the parameters I set can be nested:

```
SET A
  SET B
    READ C
    READ D
  SET B
    READ C
    READ D
SET A
  SET B
    READ C
    READ D
  SET B
    READ C
    READ D
```

I was using simple code below, but is there a more efficient way to do it?

```
import json

data = []
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        #lots of strange line filtering and keyword selection here
        #in order to build Temp vs Vdd table, etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can I be sure that the lines in the log file will be written in the same order they are executed in Python code? (this was not always true when I was simple doing "print" to the console)

If you use multiprocessing / multithreading that can happen. You need to sort out synchronisation between the processes and flushing of the buffers in that case, but the topic is too large to give any specific explanation here. If you're using only one process, no reordering is possible. If you think something was reordered, it's most likely a bug in your application.

> I was using simple code below, but is there a more efficient way to do it?

You can't make that more efficient really. It already does all the buffering you need behind the scenes. But that code shouldn't be complicated. Writing it as a few generators doing the filtering / collection of data should be quite simple.